# How to multiply a number by the second value in a list of tuples (python)?

Tags: python, tuples

I have a list of tuples that my program read from a document that begins like so:

```
(1914, 1.0)
(1915, 1.0)
(1916, 7.9)
(1917, 17.4)
(1918, 18.0)
```

What I'm trying to do is take the second number (the float) and multiply it by another number determined by the user. For example, if the user chose 14.4, the program would multiply 14.4*1.0, 14.4*1.0, 14.4*7.9, 14.4*17.4, 14.4*18.0 and so on and append it to a list. I've tried

```
[x*14.4 for x in t2[1]]
```

Where t2 is the tuple, but obviously this doesn't work and gives the TypeError "'float' object not iterable." I'm very new to python and I'm not entirely sure what to do instead.

Comment: please provide the expected output for given input

Comment: You need a way to iterate through the tuples, not just a single one. Try something wvdz's answer where t2 is a list of the tuples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given:

```
LoT=[(1914, 1.0),
(1915, 1.0),
(1916, 7.9),
(1917, 17.4),
(1918, 18.0)]
```

Since tuples are immutable, you need to create a new tuple (if you want a new list of tuples).

```
>>> x=14.4
>>> [(t[0], t[1]*x) for t in LoT]
[(1914, 14.4), (1915, 14.4), (1916, 113.76), (1917, 250.55999999999997), (1918, 259.2)]
```

If you want just a list of the second element of the tuple multiplied, you can do:

```
>>> [t[1]*x for t in LoT]
[14.4, 14.4, 113.76, 250.55999999999997, 259.2]
```

You post states:

> What I'm trying to do is take the second number (the float) and
>   multiply it by another number determined by the user.

That is why I used `[t[1]*x for t in LoT]` because `t[1]` is the second element of any tuple with at least 2 elements.

If every tuple is guaranteed to be two elements long, you can also do `[y*x for _, y in LoT]` for the same list.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
[y * 14.4 for x, y in tuples]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[x[1]*14.4 for x in t2]
```

Comment: OP said `t2` is the `tuple`, not the file iterator or `list`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I think he means 'list of tuples' there

Comment: Based on the error message, no, I think `t2` is an individual `tuple`, in which case this wouldn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
mytup = (
    (1914, 1.0),
    (1915, 1.0),
    (1916, 7.9),
    (1917, 17.4),
    (1918, 18.0)
)
x = int(sys.argv[1])
print(['%0.2f' % (b*x) for a, b in mytup])
```

results in:

```
['3.00', '3.00', '23.70', '52.20', '54.00']
```

Basically that's just a closure/anon func to consume the default generator+iterator which I'm assuming is what you want after reading your question.